# How to manage redux state object?

Tags: javascript, react-native, redux, react-redux, state

This the response data. I need to store quantity for each item when use press increment and decrement.

```
{name: "McChicken", type: "Non-Veg", price: 275, tax: 10}
{name: "Pizza", type: "Non-Veg", price: 275, tax: 10}
{name: "Burger", type: "Non-Veg", price: 275, tax: 10}
```

Redux state: **Saving State in Object-based Storage**

So its easy to update based on the key.

```
import * as types from '../actions/types';

var _ = require('lodash');

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  data: {},
  loading: false,
  error: '',
  cartData: {},
}; 

export default (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {

    case types.MENULIST_REQUEST_START:
        return { ...state, loading:true, error: '' };

    case types.MENULIST_SUCCESS:
      const newItems = _.mapKeys(array, 'name')
        return { ...state, data: newItems , loading:false, error: 'Success' };

    case types.UPDATE_ITEM: 
       return { ...state, [cartData.name]: action.payload  }

    case types.DELETE_ITEM:
      return _.omit(state, [cartData.name]: action.payload)

    case types.MENULIST_FAILED:
        return { ...state, data: {}, loading:false, error: 'Request failed' };

    default:
        return state;
  }
}
```

Getting error when I call update and delete item action.

> Error: cartData is not defined

How can I update the quantity and manage the state if response gets updated?

Comment: You are doing computed member access. So wrap your cartData.name in square brackets like this: [cartData.name]

Comment: @darthaditya  Tried. But getting ReferenceError: cartData is not defined

Comment: can you paste the entire code from your reducer?

Comment: @darthaditya update the post. Please check

Comment: Even though you have spread the state object, you still need to access the cartData which is **inside** the state object. so the correct way to access that would be to do [state.cartData.name]. Spread does not mutate the object.

Answer (score 1):

you need to change

```
{ ...state, cartData.name: action.payload  }
```

### es6 Computed property keys

```
{ ...state, [cartData.name]: action.payload  }
```

[Computed property keys](http://www.benmvp.com/learning-es6-enhanced-object-literals/)

Comment: Tried. But getting `ReferenceError: cartData is not defined`

Comment: did you initialized the state with your INITIAL_STATE object?

Comment: Yes. I'm able to get data for fetchData.

Comment: cartData object is inside the state 
{ ...state, [state.cartData.name]: action.payload } here you go :)

Comment: @GoorLavi [state.cartData.name] is undefined. Now state has `undefined: {....}`. cartData is still in initialState.

Comment: thats was your willing to know how to insert state.cartData.name value as state prop key of course state.cartData.name should be initialized before with the wanted value in it.